# CSS Changes take roughly 24 Hours to become live

Tags: magento-1.9, css, cache

I make changes on my Magento website im using 1.9.2 version and whenever i create any CSS changes the page doesn't change until the next day.

I have cleared the Cache in backend, by flushing everything System > Cache Management and no changes

I have deleted all the folders found in Var / Cache and still no changes

I have deleted all my Cache in my browser and tried different browsers/computer and no changes are happening.

I am stumped on what to try next or whats going on

Comment: Have you yried via a different internet provider / connection? Its possibke fikes are being cached by your network provider. If you request tge file direct, do you see access in access log? Consider merging your css. That will add a unique hash to the merged file. Should force an immeduate update.

Comment: is site css files serving from CDN ?

Comment: just set the ip of site in your host and try again.

Answer (score 2):

May be your hosting server using the cache. you check in the cpanel and find cache extension using by hosting provider.

for example : varnish cache, super cache and etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possibly caused by the server cache of your DNS. The server cache of DNS can be set dynamically. If you use DNS management like Cloudflare, you may clear your cache from the `Caching` > `Purge Cache` section or update the `Caching` > `Browser Cache Expiration` duration and try reloading your page.

[image: Caching]